# jQuery AJAX call to Vanilla JS, what am I missing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, linkedin-api

**UPDATE:** *I failed to mention that I already read the [suggested duplicate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28524485/xmlhttprequest-throwing-invalidsateerror-saying-object-state-must-be-opened) and it didn't get me any further as I didn't see how it related to my problem. The user **ponury-kostek** below, did however manage to explain it simply enough without all that clutter, for me to understand. So that's how I don't see it as a duplicate.*

I'm trying to implement saving user data into a database when the user logs in with LinkedIn (to keep track of who watched my page). I found a tutorial that used jQuery, and I found a [GitHub (here)](https://gist.github.com/joyrexus/7307312) page for conversion of jQuery to Vanilla JS, but I'm struggling to understand what I need to do to convert this specific statement.

I got the whole thing working using just that one line of jQuery, no problems - but I don't want to force users to load the jQuery lib!

I'll post the jQuery I'm trying to convert, the Vanilla JS solution I have so far, and the conversion "formula" suggested on the GitHub page:

**jQuery I'm trying to convert:**

```
$.post('saveUserData.php', 
  {
    oauth_provider: 'linkedin',
    userData: JSON.stringify(userData)
  }, 
  function(data){ return true; });
```

**My attempt at a Vanilla JS solution**

```
var theUrl = 'saveUserData.php';
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function (data) {

};
httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
httpRequest.open('POST', theUrl);
httpRequest.send({oauth_provider:'linkedin',userData: JSON.stringify(userData)}, function(data){ return true; });
```

Error thrown:

```
script.js:10 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED.
    at saveUserData (http://localhost:8012/linkedCV/script.js:10:14)
    at displayProfileData (http://localhost:8012/linkedCV/index.php:43:4)
    at B.<anonymous> (https://platform.linkedin.com/js/framework?v=1.0.350-1429&lang=undefined:3350:17)
    at B.runHandler (https://platform.linkedin.com/js/framework?v=1.0.350-1429&lang=undefined:172:9)
    at B.<anonymous> (https://platform.linkedin.com/js/framework?v=1.0.350-1429&lang=undefined:3355:6)
    at B.handleSuccessResults (https://platform.linkedin.com/js/framework?v=1.0.350-1429&lang=undefined:172:9)
    at Object.g [as success] (https://platform.linkedin.com/js/framework?v=1.0.350-1429&lang=undefined:3243:4)
    at Object.incoming (https://platform.linkedin.com/js/framework?v=1.0.350-1429&lang=undefined:817:38)
    at _window_onMessage (https://platform.linkedin.com/js/framework?v=1.0.350-1429&lang=undefined:581:102)
```

**My JS (in the index header):**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: thecorrectAPIkey aka 'Client ID'
    authorize: true
    onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
    scope: r_basicprofile r_emailaddress
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Setup an event listener to make an API call once auth is complete
    function onLinkedInLoad() {
        IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", getProfileData);
    }

    // Use the API call wrapper to request the member's profile data
    function getProfileData() {
        IN.API.Profile("me").fields("id", "first-name", "last-name", "headline", "location", "picture-url", "public-profile-url", "email-address").result(displayProfileData).error(onError);
    }

    // Handle the successful return from the API call
    function displayProfileData(data){
        var user = data.values[0];
        document.getElementById("picture").innerHTML = '<img src="'+user.pictureUrl+'" />';
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = user.firstName+' '+user.lastName;
        document.getElementById("intro").innerHTML = user.headline;
        document.getElementById("email").innerHTML = user.emailAddress;
        document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = user.location.name;
        document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = '<a href="'+user.publicProfileUrl+'" target="_blank">Visit profile</a>';
        document.getElementById('profileData').style.display = 'block';
        saveUserData(user);
    }

    // Handle an error response from the API call
    function onError(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    // Destroy the session of linkedin
    function logout(){
        IN.User.logout(removeProfileData);
    }

    // Remove profile data from page
    function removeProfileData(){
        document.getElementById('profileData').remove();
    }
</script>
```

**GitHub conversion suggestion:**

```
// jQuery
$.post('//example.com', { username: username }, function (data) {
  // code
})

// Vanilla
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function (data) {
  // code
}
httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
httpRequest.open('POST', url)
httpRequest.send('username=' + encodeURIComponent(username))
```

Since this works perfectly as long as I use the suggested jQuery (the one I want to convert to Vanilla JS), it all works fine. So I'm going to assume the rest of the code of my page is not needed (the PHP for the DB connection and for saving user data to the DB).

Comment: It kind of says exactly what the problem is in the error message, no?

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes, it says that it failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest' and that the object needs to be opened. Which is the object that needs to be opened and does it mean there is something wrong with the syntax in the 'httpRequest.open....' statement? So to me, it's not that obvious.

Comment: @MysterX I read that thread before this was posted, but failed to mention it. It didn't get me any further as I didn't see how it related to my problem. ponury-kostek did however manage to explain it simply enough without all that clutter, for me to understand. So that's how I don't see it as a duplicate.

Comment: ... It needs to be opened before `setRequestHeader`. You opened it after you tried calling `setRequestHeader`.

Comment: @DaveNewton yes, and the error message didn't say that in plain text (to me).

Comment: Hrm, ok. I guess I read that and think "Oh it has to be opened" ("The object's state must be OPENED") and I haven't called `open` yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader

> When using setRequestHeader(), you must call it after calling open(),
>   but before calling send().

```
var theUrl = 'saveUserData.php';
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function (data) {

};
httpRequest.open('POST', theUrl);
httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
httpRequest.send({oauth_provider:'linkedin',userData: JSON.stringify(userData)}, function(data){ return true; });
```

Comment: Brilliant! I didn't see how the suggested duplicate thread could be applied to my example, but your explanation was short, precise and to the point, and it's now seems very obvious, thus I can also remember it. I would give you more upvotes if it were possible!