# I am trying to add authorization header in AJAX call using pure JavaScript. But gives error

Tags: javascript, ajax

Here is my code snippet:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + sessionStorage.getItem("token"));
```

It gives me error like:

> core.js:1633 ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader'
>   on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XMLHttpRequest throwing InvalidSateError saying "Object state must be opened"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28524485/xmlhttprequest-throwing-invalidsateerror-saying-object-state-must-be-opened)

Comment: Hope this helps [Object state must be opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28524485/xmlhttprequest-throwing-invalidsateerror-saying-object-state-must-be-opened)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So open it but do it before setting RequestHeader, like this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'example link);
xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + sessionStorage.getItem("token"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call .open(..) before setting the request headers.

This response was paste from [this previous question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28524485/xmlhttprequest-throwing-invalidsateerror-saying-object-state-must-be-opened)